# SIMD vector interoperability between LLVM and gcc

Tags: gcc, llvm, vectorization, simd, abi

I would like to accelerate an program I'm working on by dynamically generating code with LLVM's JIT. The algorithm can operate on vectors, and I'd rather like to use the SIMD vector extensions in LLVM to do this (not only does it make some operations faster, but it actually makes the code generation simpler).

Do I stand any chance of having this work in a reasonably portable way?

On the C side of things, I'll be compiling with gcc, clang or, maybe, icc. My vectors are going to be simple `float x 4` or `double x 4` things. The de facto standard for non-platform-specific vector operations in this world appears to be the gcc vector extension:

```
typedef double Vector4 __attribute__ ((vector_size (sizeof(double)*4)));
```

Inspection of generated code shows that clang will pass a `double x 4` vector in registers, while gcc wants it on the stack --- which is bad. (They both pass `float x 4` vectors in registers.)

My understanding is that the two systems are supposed to be ABI compatible, but obviously vectors don't count. Can I actually do this?

My example program is::

```
typedef double real;
typedef real Vector4 __attribute__ ((vector_size (sizeof(real)*4)));

Vector4 scale(Vector4 a)
{
    Vector4 s = {2, 2, 2, 2};
    return a*s;
}
```

This compiles with LLVM into:

```
scale:
    movapd  .LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm2
    mulpd   %xmm2, %xmm0
    mulpd   %xmm2, %xmm1
    ret
```

...but gcc produces this horror:

```
scale:
    subq    $64, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
    movapd  72(%rsp), %xmm1
    movsd   %xmm0, -56(%rsp)
    movsd   %xmm0, -48(%rsp)
    movsd   %xmm0, -72(%rsp)
    movsd   %xmm0, -64(%rsp)
    mulpd   -56(%rsp), %xmm1
    movapd  88(%rsp), %xmm0
    mulpd   -72(%rsp), %xmm0
    movapd  %xmm1, -104(%rsp)
    movq    -104(%rsp), %rdx
    movapd  %xmm1, -24(%rsp)
    movapd  %xmm0, -8(%rsp)
    movq    %rdx, (%rdi)
    movq    -16(%rsp), %rdx
    movq    %rdx, 8(%rdi)
    movq    -8(%rsp), %rdx
    movq    %rdx, 16(%rdi)
    movq    (%rsp), %rdx
    movq    %rdx, 24(%rdi)
    addq    $64, %rsp
    ret
```

If I redefine `real` to be a `float`, I get this from both compilers (they produce identical code):

```
scale:
    mulps   .LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm0
    ret
```

These were all compiled with `$CC -O3 -S -msse test.c`.

**Update:** It suddenly occurs to me that the simple solution is to just use LLVM to create a trampoline that the translates from structures to vectors and vice versa. That way the interoperability problem is reduced to pass-by-value structures, which *are* nailed down by the ABI; the vectors only exist in LLVM-land. It means I only get to use the SIMD stuff inside LLVM, but I can live with that.

However, I would still like to know the answer to the above; vectors are awesome and I'd like to be able to use them more.

**Update update:** Turns out that the way C passes structures by value is insanely... er, insane! A `struct { double x, y, z; }` is passed by pointer; a `struct { float x, y, z }` is passed as a *pair* of %xmm registers: `x` and `y` are packed into the first, and the `z` is in the second...

Simple and unpainful it's not!

Comment: What versions of gcc and clang, and on what platform? I am not getting the same results.

Comment: No idea --- too long ago. I did discover the reason for the weird structure passing in the last update, though: return values of 128 bits or smaller get passed in registers, and since the second struct is only 96 bits, it gets packed into registers and returned that way.

Comment: C doesn't define the passing convention, the ABI does.  The reason the float struct is passed in registers is that it fits into two registers, while the double struct does not.  Assuming this is on an x86-64 SysV system, the behavior is correct.  The x86-64 System V ABI supplement has all of the details.

Comment: What ABI is clang compiling to?  Is it the same one gcc is using?  Passing vectors in registers is not standardized in the System V ABI.